# TestNG is not executing methods inside Test annotation in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

I am new to selenium webdriver, I have just installed TestNG plugin for eclipse kelpler, now when I tried to execute my code using TestNG, I am able to see the execution of the code present under @BeforeTest however the code present under @Test annotation are not getting executed.
Here is the code what I have written :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Survey_Fill {

WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void start(){
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();

        org.openqa.selenium.Dimension d = new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(1360, 1200);
         driver.manage().window().setSize(d);   
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("hello");

    }

}
```

Here is the output given by TestNG results :

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1183478272\testng-customsuite.xml


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@3379bd14: 35 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@12b2bde5: 164 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@7b3825bf: 257 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@566fbd76: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@72c25346: 13 ms
```

Please let me know the error which I have done here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running your tests using TestNG

Remove `import org.junit.Test`

Use TestNG annotations,

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Why it doesn't work,

bcoz, the test() method is derived from Junit and the start() method is using TestNG annotations, since you Run your test as TestNG test, Junit test() din't get executed.

If you run your test as Junit test, then you can see the difference.